# Butterworthfilter data filter

Tags: signal-processing, filtering, image-processing

I am currently doing a signal analysis and filtering using Matlab. The filter I am using is Butterworthfilter model to filter scattered data (vector data).

I am using Matlab as follows:

```
function [y]=fButterworthfilter(input_data,f_cut)
rng default;
[b,a] = butter(8,f_cut/(200/2));
y=filtfilt(b,a,input_data); % zero-phase filtering
```

I want to see how can I do the Butterworthfilter filtering using Mathematica.
I tried ButterworthFilterModel in the help but the input is a function not a vector data.

Let us say I have the following noisy data:

```
data1 = Table[Exp[-i^2], {i, -5, 5, .01}];
noise = RandomReal /@ RandomReal[{-0.3, 1}, Length[data]];
data2 = data1+noise;
```

How can I do Butterworthfilter filtering for this data?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Butterworth is a continuous-time recursive filter, so it needs to be translated to discrete form and then applied to the `data` using

```
 RecurrenceFilter[ToDiscreteTimeModel[ButterworthFilterModel[5], 1], data]
```

For example, with `data={1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, -1}', the output is

```
 {0.00649005, 0.0585661, 0.254294, 0.718228, 1.49564, 2.44071, 3.20403, 3.38901}
```

Comment: Thank you fro you Replay, I got your idea but I am still not getting same answer that I am getting from Matlab.
I don'e understand how to place the filtering inputs to produce same output as I am getting from. I will paste  another Question and I would appreciate it if you look at it.

Comment: The RecurrenceFilter here is like Matlab's function filt. If you want the same answer as filtfilt gives, you will have to do what filtfilt does: filter forwards and then backwards.

Comment: Thanks bill, i have done what you said, forwards and backwards filler as follows:

Reverse[
 RecurrenceFilter[
  ToDiscreteTimeModel[ButterworthFilterModel[{c, a}], b],
  
  Reverse[
   RecurrenceFilter[
    ToDiscreteTimeModel[ButterworthFilterModel[{8, 0.04}], 3.2], 
    data2]]]] 

is there any better way to do the backward and forward option?

Comment: I showed what I think is an imitation of what Matlab is doing in this answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46527/1783 If you don't want to write it all out each time, you can make a function (and call it `filtfilt`!)