# Data filtering using Butterworth filter

Tags: filtering, signal-processing

I want to filter data using Butterworth filter.
I am currently using Matlab and I want to know how to do it in Mathematica.

I have the following data:

```
data1 = Table[
   PDF[NormalDistribution[3.5, .8], i] + 
    PDF[NormalDistribution[6, 1], i], {i, -5, 15, .01}];
noise = RandomReal /@ RandomReal[{-0.2, .2}, Length[data1]];
data2 = data1 + noise;
```

I filtered this data using Matlab as follows:

```
[b,a] = butter(8,0.04);

filtfilt(b,a,data2 );
```

In the [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46380)'s answer, bill s suggested to do it as follows in Mathematica:

```
RecurrenceFilter[
 ToDiscreteTimeModel[ButterworthFilterModel[{2, 0.04}], 1], data2
 ]
```

The result is as follows:
[image]

The problem I am facing is whatever I change the filter order and frequency, I am not able to produce the same filtered data as I am getting from Matlab.

Can someone suggest for me what to do and what values to use to get the same filtered data as I am getting from Matlab?

Thanks

Comment: `filtfilt` does a forward-backward filtering. Have you tried filtering, reversing the output, filtering again and finally reversing again in Mathematica?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

filtfilt does a forwards and then a backwards filtering, as rm -rf suggests. To filter `data` in this way, you might try

```
forwards = RecurrenceFilter[ToDiscreteTimeModel[ButterworthFilterModel[5], 1], data];
backwards = RecurrenceFilter[ToDiscreteTimeModel[ButterworthFilterModel[5], 1], Reverse[data]];
(forwards + Reverse[backwards])/2
```

The nice thing about filtfilt (or the forwards/backwards filter above) is that the filtering has no phase shift/delay when compared with the original data.

Comment: Good. Great Thanks.

Comment: it is nice I upvote this answer and you edited it. this was my second question in this forum and that time I didn't know there is upvote. sorry for waiting all this time to upvote your answer :)

Comment: filtfilt is a zero-phase filter. Filters may be made to have zero phase and so prevent the filtered waveform being delayed compared to the waveform it filters, by using the procedure offered by bill s. Just need to halve the result to get the correct amplitude.