# How can i use Butterworth filter written in matlab to Mathematica

Tags: signal-processing

i need help to convert this code written in matlab about Butterworth filter:

```
 %remove high-frequency components by 0.5-h butterworth filter;
 n =2; 
 Wn =[1/30/0.5];   %30-min low-pass filter (LPF)%
 [z11, p11, k11] = butter(n,Wn,'low');
 [sos11,g11]=zp2sos(z11,p11,k11);
 [B11,A11]=sos2tf(sos11,prod(g11));
 u2=filtfilt(B11,A11,fix(u1));  
 T2=filtfilt(B11,A11,fix(T1));  
%end%
```

How can i convert this code same result in Matlab?

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps start at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46500/data-filtering-using-butterworth-filter

Comment: You may want to look at  [`ButterworthFilterModel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ButterworthFilterModel.html)

Comment: This line `u2=filtfilt(B11,A11,fix(u1));` gives error undefined `u1`. Your code does not run.